# How to activate maven profile use environment variables?

Tags: maven, maven-profiles

For some reason, I have to use environment variable instead of passing the system properties to mvn command. So, I use ${env.PROFILE} as the property name, The profile setting in the pom.xml shows as follows:

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                <property>
                    <name>${env.PROFILE}</name>
                    <value>dev</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <profile.assembly.suffix></profile.assembly.suffix>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>online</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>${env.PROFILE}</name>
                    <value>online</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <profile.assembly.suffix>-online</profile.assembly.suffix>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

then, I try to activate profile to online, but i failed, the command lines show like these:

```
E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\LobbyServer>set PROFILE=online
E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\LobbyServer>echo %PROFILE%
online

E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\LobbyServer>mvn help:active-profiles
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for Fusion:LobbyServer:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for Fusion:Fusion-Core:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/../libs/Fusion-Core-2.0.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 98, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for Fusion:common-plugin:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/../libs/common-plugin-1.0.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 106, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: redis.clients:jedis:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 227, column 21
[WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for Fusion:Fusion-Core:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/libs/Fusion-Core-2.0.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ Fusion:Fusion-Server:1.0, E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\pom.xml, line 64, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for Fusion:common-plugin:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/libs/common-plugin-${project.version}.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ Fusion:Fusion-Server:1.0, E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\pom.xml, line 72, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework:spring-core:jar -> duplicate declaration of version ${spring.version} @ Fusion:Fusion-Server:1.0, E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\pom.xml, line 167, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin is missing. @ line 67, column 21
[WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for Fusion:Fusion-Core:jar refers to a non-existing file E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\LobbyServer\libs\Fusion-Core-2.0.jar @ Fusion:Fusion-Server:1.0, E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\pom.xml, line 64, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for Fusion:common-plugin:jar refers to a non-existing file E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\LobbyServer\libs\common-plugin-1.0.jar @ Fusion:Fusion-Server:1.0, E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\pom.xml, line 72, column 25
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------< Fusion:LobbyServer >-------------------------
[INFO] Building LobbyServer 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:active-profiles (default-cli) @ LobbyServer ---
[INFO]
Active Profiles for Project 'Fusion:LobbyServer:jar:1.0':

The following profiles are active:

 - dev (source: Fusion:LobbyServer:1.0)



[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.661 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-06T12:48:49+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then I open the maven debug mode(-X), the properties look like these:

```
[DEBUG] properties used {spring-data-common.version=1.12.6.RELEASE, file.encoding.pkg=sun.io, env.PROMPT=$P$G, okhttp3.version=3.8.1, java.home=D:\Software\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre, env.CLION=D:\Software\CLion 2019.1.4\bin;, classworlds.conf=E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\BuildTool\maven\bin\..\bin\m2.conf, profile.assembly.suffix=, java.endorsed.dirs=D:\Software\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\endorsed, env.USERNAME=zhengtongshan, env.PHPSTORM=D:\Software\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2019.2.2\bin;, servlet.version=3.1.0, sun.os.patch.level=, java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/, env.COMPUTERNAME=DESKTOP-R7DT0R0, env.=C:=C:\Users\zhengtongshan, java.version=1.8.0_121, commons-beanutils.version=1.9.3, env.DRIVERDATA=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData, fastjson.version=1.2.62, spring-data-redis.version=1.8.4.RELEASE, java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/, env.USERPROFILE=C:\Users\zhengtongshan, apache.httpclient.version=4.5.3, jedis.version=2.9.0, user.name=zhengtongshan, sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle, sun.jnu.encoding=GBK, java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, env.LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\zhengtongshan\AppData\Local, env.COMMONPROGRAMW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files, java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification, user.timezone=Asia/Shanghai, user.script=, path.separator=;, env.MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS=-e  -X -f E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\BuildTool\../RoomServer/pom.xml clean assembly:assembly, env.PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel, file.encoding=GBK, sun.java.command=org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -e -X -f E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\BuildTool\../RoomServer/pom.xml clean assembly:assembly, env.NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=12, env.APPDATA=C:\Users\zhengtongshan\AppData\Roaming, env.WINDIR=C:\Windows, java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\ZHENGT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\, user.language=zh, line.separator=
, env.COMMONPROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files\Common Files, java.vm.info=mixed mode, sun.desktop=windows, java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, project.reporting.outputEncoding=UTF-8, env.PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC, env.WDIR=E:\, env.ONEDRIVE=C:\Users\zhengtongshan\OneDrive, env.USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=DESKTOP-R7DT0R0, commons-io.version=2.5, trove4j.version=3.0.3, env.LOGONSERVER=\\DESKTOP-R7DT0R0, env.PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules, java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob, commons-codec.version=1.9, env.JAVACMD=D:\Software\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe, env.JVMCONFIG=\.mvn\jvm.config, env.PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public, env.USERDOMAIN=DESKTOP-R7DT0R0, env.PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6, env.PROGRAMFILES(X86)=C:\Program Files (x86), env.=EXITCODE=00000000, env.FILE_ARG=E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\BuildTool\../RoomServer/pom.xml, os.name=Windows 10, java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, env.TMP=C:\Users\ZHENGT~1\AppData\Local\Temp, java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, env.OS=Windows_NT, java.library.path=D:\Software\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;D:\Software\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\Software\TortoiseSVN\bin;D:\Software\Git\cmd;E:\FusionDB\mongodb-3.2.17\bin;E:\FusionDB\Redis-x64-3.2.100;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;D:\Software\Cygwin\bin;D:\Software\Calibre2\;D:\Software\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin\;D:\Software\apache-maven-3.6.2-bin\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin;D:\Software\Python3.6\Scripts\;D:\Software\Python3.6\;C:\Users\zhengtongshan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;D:\Software\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 193.4386.10\bin;;D:\Software\JetBrains\JetBrains Rider 2019.1.2\bin;;D:\Software\CLion 2019.1.4\bin;;D:\Software\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2019.2.2\bin;;., env.PROGRAMW6432=C:\Program Files, env.PATH=D:\Software\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\Software\TortoiseSVN\bin;D:\Software\Git\cmd;E:\FusionDB\mongodb-3.2.17\bin;E:\FusionDB\Redis-x64-3.2.100;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;D:\Software\Cygwin\bin;D:\Software\Calibre2\;D:\Software\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin\;D:\Software\apache-maven-3.6.2-bin\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin;D:\Software\Python3.6\Scripts\;D:\Software\Python3.6\;C:\Users\zhengtongshan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;D:\Software\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 193.4386.10\bin;;D:\Software\JetBrains\JetBrains Rider 2019.1.2\bin;;D:\Software\CLion 2019.1.4\bin;;D:\Software\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2019.2.2\bin;, library.jansi.path=E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\BuildTool\maven\bin\..\lib\jansi-native\windows64, java.class.version=52.0, maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\BuildTool, javaxValidation.version=1.1.0.Final, env.HOMEDRIVE=C:, env.SYSTEMROOT=C:\Windows, spring.version=4.3.9.RELEASE, env.COMSPEC=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe, sun.boot.library.path=D:\Software\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin, project.build.sourceEncoding=UTF-8, env.SYSTEMDRIVE=C:, env.PROCESSOR_REVISION=9e0a, sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers, java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment, user.variant=, mongo-java-driver.version=3.3.0, netty.version=4.1.6.Final, junit.version=RELEASE, env.PROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files, java.vm.specification.version=1.8, env.POM_DIR=E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\RoomServer, env.PROGRAMDATA=C:\ProgramData, slf4j.version=1.7.25, awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit, env.MAVEN_HOME=E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\BuildTool\maven\bin\.., sun.cpu.isalist=amd64, sun.stderr.encoding=ms936, env.MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR=E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\BuildTool, java.ext.dirs=D:\Software\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext, os.version=10.0, env.ERROR_CODE=0, user.home=C:\Users\zhengtongshan, env.PROFILE=online, java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, env.JETBRAINS RIDER=D:\Software\JetBrains\JetBrains Rider 2019.1.2\bin;, env.JAVA_HOME=D:\Software\Java\jdk1.8.0_121, user.dir=E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\BuildTool, maven.conf=E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\BuildTool\maven\bin\../conf, env.COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files, log4j.version=2.8.2, sun.cpu.endian=little, spring-data-mongo.version=1.10.4.RELEASE, env.ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData, env.CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER=org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher, env.PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64, java.vm.version=25.121-b13, java.class.path=E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\BuildTool\maven\bin\..\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar, env.=::=::\, org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=debug, env.HOMEPATH=\Users\zhengtongshan, env.EXEC_DIR=E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\BuildTool, os.arch=amd64, maven.build.version=Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-04T03:39:06+08:00), env.SESSIONNAME=Console, guava.version=19.0, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, file.separator=\, gson.version=2.7, java.runtime.version=1.8.0_121-b13, sun.boot.class.path=D:\Software\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\resources.jar;D:\Software\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\Software\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;D:\Software\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jsse.jar;D:\Software\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jce.jar;D:\Software\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\charsets.jar;D:\Software\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\jfr.jar;D:\Software\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\classes, env.CMAKE_C_COMPILER=D:/Software/Cygwin/bin/gcc.exe, jackson.version=2.8.9, maven.version=3.5.0, env.TEMP=C:\Users\ZHENGT~1\AppData\Local\Temp, user.country=CN, maven.home=E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\BuildTool\maven\bin\.., maven.compiler.target=1.8, env.=E:=E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\BuildTool, commons-lang3.version=3.6, env.INTELLIJ IDEA=D:\Software\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 193.4386.10\bin;, commons-pool2.version=2.4.2, java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, env.CLASSWORLDS_JAR="E:\Tetris\src\1_Branches\rtm_tetris_zhugan\Server\BuildTool\maven\bin\..\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar", protobuf.version=3.2.0, maven.compiler.source=1.8, java.specification.version=1.8, sun.arch.data.model=64, argLine=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8}
```

We can find the properties on above properties list：

```
env.PROFILE=online, profile.assembly.suffix=,
```

It seems the "PROFILE" variable has been setted in envrionment. However, the "online" profile is not activated. What's the problem? thanks.

Comment: What do you not activate the profile via `mvn -Pprofile` ?

Answer (score 14):

Replace `<name>${env.PROFILE}</name>` to `<name>env.PROFILE</name>` and try running `mvn help:active-profiles`, you should get the online profile.

```
C:\Sachin\data\development\app_code\spring-security-demo>mvn help:active-profiles
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building spring-security-demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-help-plugin:3.1.1:active-profiles (default-cli) @ spring-security-demo ---
[INFO]
Active Profiles for Project 'com.security.example:spring-security-demo:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT':

The following profiles are active:

 - online (source: com.security.example:spring-security-demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)
```

Below is the updated profile tag

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>env.PROFILE</name>
                <value>dev</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <profile.assembly.suffix></profile.assembly.suffix>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>online</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env.PROFILE</name>
                <value>online</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <profile.assembly.suffix>-online</profile.assembly.suffix>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

You could also use `mvn help:all-profiles` which would list all profiles with its Active status. For ex. for your example if we have set the PROFILE value to online running `mvn help:all-profiles` should display as below

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building spring-security-demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-help-plugin:3.1.1:all-profiles (default-cli) @ spring-security-demo ---
[INFO] Listing Profiles for Project: com.security.example:spring-security-demo:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  Profile Id: online (Active: true , Source: pom)
  Profile Id: dev (Active: false , Source: pom)
```

I tested it using maven `3.2.5` in windows 10 OS.

Answer (score 5):

You are very close. When referencing environment variables, you shouldn't use `${...}` but simply `env.VARIABLE`.

A slightly adjusted example to illustrate what I mean:

`SET PROFILE=online`

**POM**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>profiles</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>profiles</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>prof-1</id>
      <activation>
         <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
         <property>
           <name>env.PROFILE</name>
           <value>dev</value>
         </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
         <profile.assembly.suffix>-dev</profile.assembly.suffix>
      </properties>            
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>prof-2</id>
      <activation>
         <property>
            <name>env.PROFILE</name>
            <value>online</value>
         </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
         <profile.assembly.suffix>-online</profile.assembly.suffix>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>print-profile</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <configuration>
              <target>
                <echo message="profile assembly: ${profile.assembly.suffix}"/>
              </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>  
</project>
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
mvn validate
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------< org.example:profiles >------------------------
[INFO] Building profiles 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (print-profile) @ profiles ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [echo] profile assembly: -online
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.624 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-06T10:10:18+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Not working in my case, trying to activate a profile from a specific value and still nothing